# pgfkeys: Read one key and ignore the others

Tags: pgfkeys, optional-arguments, arguments, parameters

In my own command `\includegraphicsextended` I want to add a caption to the pdf page containing

> File [filename] Page [pagenumber]

therefore from the keys in `%1` I want to just read the `page=...` key and ignore all other keys like `trim=...` and `clip` because they must only get forwarded to `\includegraphics` but I don't want to specify all possible keys of `\includegraphics`. I would prefer to be able to set it like *get the page key and ignore all the others*.

I want to execute `\includegraphicsextended` like this:

```
\includegraphicsextended[trim=35mm 163mm 35mm 28mm,clip,page=22]{file.pdf}
```

And `\includegraphicsextended` should then look something like this:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicsextended}[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{#1}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
        \caption{File \detokenize{#2} Page \pgfkeyPage}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.unknown` key handler to build up a list that gets forwarded to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfkeys{/Silvan/.cd,}
\newcommand{\includegraphicsextended}[2][]{\begingroup
    \def\rawkey/##1\relax{\edef\mykey{##1}}%
    \let\lstgrph\relax
    \edef\pgfkeyPage{0}%
    \pgfkeys{/handlers/.unknown/.code={\expandafter\rawkey\pgfkeyscurrentkey\relax
    \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\pgfkeysnovalue\pgfkeyscurrentvalue\relax
        %\typeout{no value}
    \else
        \edef\mykey{\mykey=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue}%
    \fi
    \ifx\lstgrph\relax
    \edef\lstgrph{\mykey}%
    \else
    \edef\lstgrph{\lstgrph,\mykey}%
    \fi},page/.code=\edef\pgfkeyPage{##1}}%
    \pgfkeys{#1}%
    \begin{figure}[H]
         \edef\temp{\noexpand\includegraphics[\lstgrph]{#2}}%
         \centering\temp
         \caption{File \detokenize{#2} Page \pgfkeyPage}
    \end{figure}\endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsextended[trim=35mm 163mm 35mm 28mm,clip,page=22]{example-image-duck.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]